# Where can I find a super drop down menu with images and text details?

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm curious how to build a similar menu with all the images and text details as in http://www.resellerclub.com/

Any ideas on the technologies used ? Are there any commercial solutions like this ?

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Super drop down menu with images and text details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657168/super-drop-down-menu-with-images-and-text-details)

Answer (score 1):

They are called 'mega menu' plugins. You can build them with a combination of CSS/Javascript/jQuery. There are several open source plugins available.

You can try: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerymegamenu

This article talks about several menu plugins: http://www.noupe.com/jquery/45-jquery-navigation-plugins-and-tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps would this [non-Javascript example](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) help? It's HTML and CSS3 entirely, with some scripts for browser support.