# Super drop down menu with images and text details

Tags: javascript, css

I'm curious how to build a similar menu with all the images and text details as in
http://www.resellerclub.com/

Any ideas on the technologies used ? Are there any commercial solutions like this ?

Thank you,

Comment: Seems like this is duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657069/where-can-i-find-a-super-drop-down-menu-with-images-and-text-details/6657110#6657110

Answer (score 1):

Telerik makes a Rad Combobox, that lets you stuff pretty much whatever you want into a drop down easily. If you are working with Silverlight or WPF, you can roll your own very easily as well by defining an item template and applying it to a combobox, since you can embed controls inside other controls through XAML.

Answer (score 1):

There's this [popular drop down menu in ThemeForest](http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-mega-drop-down-menu/126387).

It doesn't look exactly like the one you posted but it seems very versatile.

Answer (score 1):

They are called 'mega menu' plugins. You can build them with a combination of CSS/Javascript/jQuery. There are several open source plugins available.

You can try: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerymegamenu

This article talks about several menu plugins: http://www.noupe.com/jquery/45-jquery-navigation-plugins-and-tutorials.html